# I'm getting an error in content provider, that is probably thread-safety specific

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-contentprovider

I'm pretty new to Android development. I've studied documentation and read tons of tutorials on how to do this and that, but 1 issue is still bothering me.

My project has 3 entities: authors, novels and chapters.

I have a fragment with list of the newest chapters published on a certain server, that dynamically loads more items when it's scrolled to the bottom (using LoaderManager). The mechanism is like this: fragment queries the SQLite database for limited number of records, and content provider responsible for the uri calls service (my own) to download more chapters and save them to the databese. Content observer for that particular uri is than notified and the fragment's list is refreshed.

Every time I scroll down in the list too fast (I guess app is downloading and inserting new content while trying to load new data from the DB) I get this error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(689): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DatabaseService]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader/databases/Live
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:503)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:416)
    at cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Downloader.LiveProvider.bulkInsertOrUpdate(LiveProvider.java:2040)
    at cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Downloader.LiveProvider.bulkInsert(LiveProvider.java:1804)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkInsert(ContentProvider.java:207)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.bulkInsert(ContentResolver.java:925)
    at cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Downloader.DatabaseService.onHandleIntent(DatabaseService.java:90)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Line 2040 is marked in the source code below.
I get another error when I try to scroll up while loading (downloading and inserting) more data, I get another error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #4
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:388)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 4 more
```

What I understood from the error message is that query method of content provider is closing writeable database. I guess it has something to do with thread-safety of the content provider. As a temporary workaround of the thread-safety issue I created a service (DatabaseService) which is responsible only for database write operations (to execute them sequentially). I think I understand the basics of using multiple threads in java, but it is too much for me to apply the knowledge to this certain problem so I came here to ask for help.

Here is the complete source of **the frament with the list**

```
package cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Fragments;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Library.ReaderActivity;
import cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.R;
import cz.muni.fi.WebNovelReader.Tools.Provider;

public class LiveNewestChaptersFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    Uri uri;
    ListView list;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    View footer = null;

    int offset;
    int lastEverVisible = 0;
    int count = 0;
    boolean loadingMore = false;

    String orderBy = Provider.Columns.CHAPTER_PUBLISHED;
    String sortOrder = " DESC";

    /* **********************
    *   Fragment Lifecycle  *
    ************************/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_servers_fragment, container, false);
        list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                //what is the bottom item that is visible
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                if (lastEverVisible < lastInScreen)
                    lastEverVisible = lastInScreen;

                //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
                if ((totalItemCount >= 10) && (lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && (lastEverVisible == lastInScreen) && !(loadingMore)){
                    if (footer != null)
                        footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    offset += 10;
                    loadingMore = true;
                    count = totalItemCount;
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null,         LiveNewestChaptersFragment.this);
                }
            }
        });

        footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_footer, null, false);
        footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list.addFooterView(footer);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        uri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();

        offset = 0;
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.live_newest_chapters_item,
                null,
                new String[] {Provider.Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX, Provider.Columns.CHAPTER_TITLE, Provider.Columns.NOVEL_TITLE, Provider.Columns.AUTHOR_NICKNAME},
                new int[] {R.id.chapter_index, R.id.chapter_title, R.id.novel_title, R.id.author_nickname},
                0
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ReaderActivity.class);
        i.setData(ContentUris.appendId(
                Provider.BaseUris.LIVE.buildUpon().path(Provider.UriPaths.CHAPTERS),
                id
        ).build());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /* **********************************
    *   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks   *
    ************************************/

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                uri,
                new String[] {Provider.Columns.BASE_ID, Provider.Columns.CHAPTER_TITLE, Provider.Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX, Provider.Columns.NOVEL_TITLE, Provider.Columns.AUTHOR_NICKNAME},
                null,
                new String[] {String.valueOf(offset + 10)},
                orderBy + " COLLATE LOCALIZED" + sortOrder
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > count) {
            if (footer != null)
                footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            loadingMore = false;
        }
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
        if (loader.isStarted())
            loader.reset();
    }
}
```

**simplified query method**

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] proj, String sel, String[] selectionArgs, String orderBy) {
    String selection = sel;

    String[] projection;
    if ((proj == null) || (proj.length == 0)) {
        projection = new String[] {"*"};
    }else{
        projection = new String[proj.length];
        System.arraycopy(proj, 0, projection, 0, proj.length);
    }
    String table;
    String groupBy = null;
    String limit = null;
    StringBuilder temp;

    boolean distinct = false;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        // initialize variables needed to make the query
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = null;
    try{
        result = db.query(distinct, table, projection, selection, SelectionArgs, groupBy, null, orderBy, limit);
        if (result != null) {
            result.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

            if ((uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_CHAPTERS_BY_SERVER_ID) && (ContentUris.parseId(uri) == 0)) {
                int offset = Integer.valueOf(limit);
                if (lastLiveLimit < offset) {
                    lastLiveLimit = offset;
                    DownloaderItemContent download = new DownloaderItemContent(url, insertUri);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), DownloaderService.class);
                    i.putExtra(DownloaderService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ITEM, download);
                    getContext().startService(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("WebNovel Reader", "LibraryProvider: query(): SQLiteException thrown:\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    return result;
}
```

**simplified bulkInsert method**
A note to the source: I use bulkInsert method to insert data. I need all 3 entities together to run checks so I decided to structure the array of ContentValues to get all 3 entities in single method call. The structure is: author content values followed by content values of this author's novel followed by content values of this novel's chapters one after another. Next content values are the ones of another author's novel and so on (pattern [author1, novel1, chapter1, chapter2, novel2, chapter1, chapter2, author2, novel1, chapter1]). It is similar to serializing tree graphs by DFS and then putting them one after another.

```
private int bulkInsertOrUpdate(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    //basic checking
    .
    .
    .
    //loop through authors
    while (i < values.length) {
        int offset = 0;
        List<ContentValues> novels_with_children = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
        List<ContentValues[]> chapters = new ArrayList<ContentValues[]>();
        int max1 = 0;

        // check if content values of author or identifier of child count are incorrect. If so, skip to the next author

        // shift 1 array entry to novel content values
        offset++;
        // loop through author's novels
        for (int j = 0; j < max1; j++) {

            int novelIndex = i + offset;
            int max2;
             // check if content values of novel or identifier of child count are incorrect. If so, skip to the next novel

            // shift  1 array entry to chapter content values
            offset++;
            ContentValues[] temp = new ContentValues[max2];
            for (int a = 0; a < max2; a++) {
                temp[a] = null;
            }

            boolean flag_empty = true;
            // loop through chapters
            for (int k = 0; k < max2; k++) {
                // check if content values of chapter or identifier of child count are incorrect. If so, skip to the next chapter


                // at least 1 chapter was added, novel is not without chapters
                flag_empty = false;
            }

            // if novel has no chapters skip it

            offset += max2;

            // if novel is OK, add it for SQLite insert
            novels_with_children.add(values[novelIndex]);
            // add novel chapters for SQLite insert
            chapters.add(temp);
        }

        // if author has no novels skip him

        /****************
         *  ACTIVE SQL  *
         ****************/

         boolean authorInserted = false;
         boolean novelInserted = false;
         boolean chapterInserted = false;

         int count_author_instance = 0;
         int count_novel_instance = 0;

         serverID = values[i].getAsLong(Columns.AUTHOR_SERVER_ID);

         picturesToDownload.clear();

         String authorPictureUrl = values[i].getAsString(Columns.AUTHOR_PICTURE);
         if (values[i].containsKey(Columns.AUTHOR_PICTURE))
             values[i].remove(Columns.AUTHOR_PICTURE);

         SQLiteDatabase dbwrite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         SQLiteStatement insertGenresChaptersConnector = dbwrite.compileStatement ("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + Tables.GENRES_CHAPTERS_CONNECTOR + "(" + Columns.CHAPTER_ID + ", " + Columns.GENRE_ID + ", " + Columns.NOVEL_ID + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

         //transaction author start
(2040)  dbwrite.beginTransaction();
        try{
            // serach for author
             Cursor authorIDcursor = dbwrite.query(Tables.AUTHORS, new String[] {Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.AUTHOR_NICKNAME + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.AUTHOR_SERVER_ID + " = ?)", new String[]{values[i].getAsString(Columns.AUTHOR_NICKNAME), Integer.toString(values[i].getAsInteger(Columns.AUTHOR_SERVER_ID))}, null, null, null);
            long authorID;
            boolean flag_transaction2_successful = false;

            if (authorIDcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                // if found, get his id
                authorID = authorIDcursor.getInt(0);
            }else{
                // create if not found
                authorID = dbwrite.insert(Tables.AUTHORS, null, values[i]);
            }
            authorIDcursor.close();

            // for every author's novel
            for (int j = 0; j < novels_with_children.size(); j++) {
                ContentValues cvn = novels_with_children.get(j);
                ContentValues[] cvc = chapters.get(j);
                boolean flag_transaction3_successful = false;

                //transaction novel start
                dbwrite.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    // search for novel
                    Cursor novelIDcursor = dbwrite.query(Tables.NOVELS, new String[]{Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_TITLE + " = ?)", new String[]{cvn.getAsString(Columns.NOVEL_TITLE)}, null, null, null);
                    long novelID;

                    if (novelIDcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        // if found get its id
                        novelID = novelIDcursor.getInt(0);
                    }else{
                        //create if not found
                        novelID = dbwrite.insert(Tables.NOVELS, null, cvn);
                    }
                    novelIDcursor.close();

                    // for every chapter
                    for (ContentValues chapterCV : cvc) {
                        //skip if chapter did not pass through initial control tests
                        if (chapterCV == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        //find previous chapter if exists
                        Cursor previous = dbwrite.query(Tables.CHAPTERS, new String[] {Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_ID + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX + " = ?)", new String[] {String.valueOf(novelID), String.valueOf(chapterIndex - 1)}, null, null, null);
                        if ((previous != null) && (previous.moveToFirst()))
                            chapterCV.put(Columns.CHAPTER_ID_PREVIOUS, previous.getLong(previous.getColumnIndex(Columns.BASE_ID)));
                        previous.close();

                        //find next chapter if exists
                        Cursor next = dbwrite.query(Tables.CHAPTERS, new String[] {Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_ID + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX + " = ?)", new String[] {String.valueOf(novelID), String.valueOf(chapterIndex + 1)}, null, null, null);
                        if ((next != null) && (next.moveToFirst()))
                            chapterCV.put(Columns.CHAPTER_ID_NEXT, next.getLong(next.getColumnIndex(Columns.BASE_ID)));
                        next.close();

                        //transaction chapter start
                        dbwrite.beginTransaction();

                        try {
                            // search for chapter
                            Cursor chapterIDcursor = dbwrite.query(Tables.CHAPTERS, new String[]{Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_ID + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX + " = ?)", new String[]{Long.toString(novelID), chapterCV.getAsInteger(Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX).toString()}, null, null, null);
                            long chapterID;

                            if (chapterIDcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                // if found get its id
                                chapterID = chapterIDcursor.getInt(0);
                            } else {
                                // create if not found
                                chapterID = dbwrite.insert(Tables.CHAPTERS, null, chapterCV);
                            }
                            chapterIDcursor.close();

                            // use pre-compiled statement to create connection between genre and chapter (insert entry into connector table)
                            for (byte genreID : genres) {
                                insertGenresChaptersConnector.bindLong(1, chapterID);
                                insertGenresChaptersConnector.bindLong(2, genreID);
                                insertGenresChaptersConnector.bindLong(3, novelID);
                                insertGenresChaptersConnector.executeInsert();
                            }

                            //tie consequent chapters together
                            //write this chapter as NEXT in previous chapter if exests
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put(Columns.CHAPTER_ID_PREVIOUS, chapterID);
                            dbwrite.update(Tables.CHAPTERS, cv, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_ID + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX + " = ?)", new String[] {String.valueOf(novelID), String.valueOf(chapterIndex + 1)});//Tables.CHAPTERS, new String[]{Columns.BASE_ID}, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_TITLE + " = ?)", new String[]{novelValues.getAsString(Columns.AUTHOR_NICKNAME)}, null, null, null);

                            //write this chapter as PREVIOUS in next chapter if exests
                            cv.clear();
                            cv.put(Columns.CHAPTER_ID_NEXT, chapterID);
                            dbwrite.update(Tables.CHAPTERS, cv, "(" + Columns.NOVEL_ID + " = ?) AND (" + Columns.CHAPTER_INDEX + " = ?)", new String[] {String.valueOf(novelID), String.valueOf(chapterIndex - 1)});



                            //if chapter and connector entries added successfully
                            dbwrite.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            flag_transaction3_successful = true;
                            count_novel_instance++;
                        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                            //TODO Log
                        } finally {
                            //transaction chapter end
                            dbwrite.endTransaction();
                        }
                    }

                    // if at least one chapter of this novel was successfully added
                    if (flag_transaction3_successful) {
                        dbwrite.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        flag_transaction2_successful = true;
                        count_novel_instance++;
                    }else{
                        count_novel_instance = 0;
                    }
                }catch(SQLiteException e) {
                    count_novel_instance = 0;
                    //TODO Log
                }finally {
                    //transaction novel end
                    dbwrite.endTransaction();
                }
            }

            count_author_instance += count_novel_instance;

            // if at least one novel of this author was successfully added
            if (flag_transaction2_successful) {
                dbwrite.setTransactionSuccessful();
                count_author_instance++;
            }else{
                count_author_instance = 0;
            }

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            count_author_instance = 0;
            //log
        }finally {
            //transaction1 end
            dbwrite.endTransaction();
            dbwrite.close();
        }

        count += count_author_instance;

        i += offset;
    }

    // notify all uris to be notified

    return count;
}
```

Thank you in advance. If any other info is needed just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is (as you noted) _extremely_ long and extremely hard to follow. Consider revising and removing any unnecessary details and log / code snippets? Perhaps (opening paragraph) (code) (error) (this is what I think) (closing paragraph)?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried to simplify it and I hope it is now easier to understand.

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you for editing. I removed the edit notice at the top as the revision history is available by clicking the 'edited' link at the bottom of every question and answer. Good luck!

Comment: You probably had problem in your `DatabaseService`. I received a similar message in LogCat and the mistake I made was accessing the Database after I calling `close()`.

Comment: @Sufian: Thanks for your suggestion, it is really appreciated. I've already thought the topic dead. DatabaseService was just experimental workaround for LiveProvider to serialize db access. I've checked implementation and as per documentation, I'm always getting new writable db at the beginning of a method and close it at the end, and readable one in the query(). The problem I'm seeing is that one thread calls close while another is still reading / writing. I've advanced since and I'm currently working on another project dealing with threads, so I'll look more into it. Thanks again.

Comment: @WrongASP I think you could have used a method which was `synchronized` on a `Object lock` and only close the DB if the counter became zero. I've used `synchronized` quite a lot in the past month, so I might help in future. :)